# Codeigniter url redirects to online server. Iam unable to find where is issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to modify a project . I get the code . This application is developed in codeigniter.when i copy this project to localhost and hit the url : localhost/project
This url redirect my website from local to www.laundruae.con
I have made the following modifications in config, route and htaccess but issue remains same. 
-i set base_url ='' in config.php 
-i set default_controller = ''  in route.php

Comment: Use the global search feature of your text editor to look for the domain name in your files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `base_url` with your website link 
   `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.laundruae.con/';`
2. Add `url` in `config/autoload.php` 
    `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
3. Set your default controller in `route.php`

Comment: I try all these points but not working on local. It redirects to online server again

Comment: what do you need? redirect to online or local or other? can you please show your controller code?